# Dynamic 2D Array Creation Runtime Error

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, malloc

I'm trying to create a multidimentional int array with the following function code:

```
int ** createIntMatrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols) 
    {

  int ** matrix;
  unsigned int i,j;

  matrix = (int **) calloc(cols, sizeof(int *));

  for(i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int *) calloc(rows, sizeof(int));


  for(i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < rows; j++)
      matrix[i][j] = 0;

  return matrix;
}
```

I create three instances using this function in the following code,

```
cout<<"allocating temporary data holders..."<<endl;
  int ** temp_meanR;
  int ** temp_meanG;
  int ** temp_meanB;
  temp_meanR = createIntMatrix(img->height,img->width);
  temp_meanG = createIntMatrix(img->height,img->width);
  temp_meanB = createIntMatrix(img->height,img->width);
cout<<"....done!"<<endl;
```

I'm accessing these elements like `temp_meanB[4][5]`.

But unfortunately, I get the following error during runtime:

```
allocating temporary data holders...
....done!
tp6(1868) malloc: *** error for object 0x122852e08: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: why are you using calloc instead of new?

Comment: no need to initialize elements to zero manually if you allocate memory with `calloc`. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/calloc/ all bits are set 0 automatically.

Comment: malloc is the C way, use new in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  for(i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    for(j = 0; i < rows; i++)
       matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

note the inside for loop, it says `j=0; i<rows; i++` (*before Aarohi Johal's edit*)

Next you do not have to set the memory manually to 0, as `calloc` does it for you.

In C++, you should use `new` and `delete` .

In the code segment

```
matrix = (int **) calloc(cols, sizeof(int *));

for(i = 0; i < cols; i++)
  matrix[i] = (int *) calloc(rows, sizeof(int));
```

I think first the rows should be allocated and then for each row link the `int` arrays.

Visulize like this:

```
        +--------+
        | matrix |
        +--------+
          |            c  o  l  s
          |     +----------------------------+
          V     |                            |
   +--  +---+   +---+---+---+       +---+
   |    |   |-->|   |   |   | . . . |   |
   |    +---+   +---+---+---+       +---+
   |    |   |--+
 r |    +---+  |   +---+---+---+       +---+
 o |    |   |  +-->|   |   |   | . . . |   |
 w |    +---+      +---+---+---+       +---+
 s .      .
   .      .
   .      .
   |    |   |
   |    +---+   +---+---+---+       +---+
   |    |   |-->|   |   |   | . . . |   |
   +--  +---+   +---+---+---+       +---+
```

First do the rows and then the cols, in the above visualization, then the `arr[i][j]` interpretation would be like normal array.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. And I fixed the typo for the i,j loops in the code.

Comment: also note the order you are allocating the rows and cols, am i clear with the diagram what i am saying, about the row-col order of the allocation? In your code, actually the `rows` is acting as columns and the `cols` is acting as rows.

Comment: That was exactly what was wrong. I compiled successfully as a result of your post :)